# jQuery or Underscore.js template caused XML parser error in thymleaf

Tags: xml, parsing, underscore.js, thymeleaf, underscore.js-templating

I have a underscore or jQuery template in my HTML file. It is something like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="myId">
    <h1><%=catalog.title %></h2>
    <div class="action">
         <% if(isGood) { %>
           we are good
       <% } else { %>
           we are not good
       <% } %>
    </div>
</script>
```

It is perfectly fine if I put this in a .jsp file or .vm file.

But if using ThymeLeaf, then I will have a parse issue. I guess it is caused by the thymeleaf XML parser. It doesn't allow something like "<%".

I can not use CDATA because if I do so, then the CDATA would be part of the template (used by the Underscore.js library).

I can not change the "<" to "& lt;". The Underscore.js/jQuery template library will not understand it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid Thymeleaf parser exceptions you might want to change the ERB-style delimiters to the Mustache.js style (or any other) according to the [underscore.js documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template) by simply inserting the following JavaScript code before any other Underscore.JS related code:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Example: Instead of

```
<h1><%=catalog.title %></h2>
```

you would write

```
<h1>{{ catalog.title }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem when using Handlebars.js templates (using {{foo}} notation). For me setting Thymeleaf to [HTML5 Legacy Template mode](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html) worked (following the advice given [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/261)). I've also had to add nekohtml to the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of futility, I finally was able to render an Underscore template within the confines of Thymeleaf XHTML mode, after stumbling upon [this similar Thymeleaf-Ember question and answer](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/261#issuecomment-35145916). All permutations of CDATA and Thymeleaf tags were failing for me until I inserted an extra random comment after the CDATA tag, as such:

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-template">
    <![CDATA[
    <!-- guard comment to prevent browsers from considering the previous and next lines as part of a comment -->
    <tr>
        <td><%- myParam%></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ]]> -->
</script>
```